# powershell Write-Output with >> to a file.txt -Append

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10

I am creating a script and want to both use Write-Host and Write-Output
As I work I want a backup of information I pull from AD to also become attached to a .txt file. 
This is more of a backup in case I miss a piece of information and need to go back and recreate a ticket. Anyways I have a sample of my script, form what I can tell it should be working. If someone with a bit more experience can take a look or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. If I need to add any more of the script I can provide this.  Thanks in Advance.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$object = Get-ADUser $sid -Properties * | Select-Object EmailAddress
Write-Host Email: $object.EmailAddress
Write-Output ("Email: $object.EmailAddress") >> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt -Append
```

This will create the .txt file of course but is also add other information such as:

```
Email: @{GivenName=myfirstname; Surname=mylastname; SamAccountName=myid; DisplayName=lastname, firstname - Contingent Worker; City=; EmailAddress=myemailaddress@mywork.com; EmployeeID=; Enabled=True; OfficePhone=; MobilePhone=(555) 555-5555; LockedOut=False; LockOutTime=0; AccountExpirationDate=05/09/2020 00:00:00; PasswordExpired=False; PasswordLastSet=12/03/2019 12:16:37}.EmailAddress
-Append
```

I am looking to have the output like the following...

```
name: username
email: user email address
phone: user phone number
etc...
```

All general information from Active Directory

Thanks again for the suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use write-output. Use `(Get-ADUser $sid -properties mail).mail`.
Like this:

```
Add-Content -Path "FilePath" -Value "Email: $((Get-ADUser $sid -properties mail).mail)"
```

Answer (score 3):

> `Write-Output ("Email: $object.EmailAddress")`

<sup>As an aside: No need for `(...)` here.</sup>

This doesn't do what you expect it to: it stringifies `$object` *as a whole* and then appends `.EmailAddress` *verbatim*; **in order to embed an *expression*, such as *accessing a property* inside `"..."` (an expandable string), you need `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**.

```
Write-Output "Email: $($object.EmailAddress)" >> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt
```

<sup>See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of the syntax in PowerShell expandable strings.</sup>

Or, more simply, **using PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior (use of `Write-Output` is rarely necessary)**:

```
"Email: $($object.EmailAddress)" >> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt
```

> `>> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt -Append`

**`>>` is effectively an alias for `Out-File -Append`** (just like `>` is for just `Out-File`), so not only is there no *need* for `-Append`, it *isn't interpreted by `>>`*, which accepts *only* the filename operand.
Instead, **`-Append` was interpreted by `Write-Output`**, which is why it ended up literally in your output file.
Perhaps surprisingly, while a redirection such as `>> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt` is *typically* placed *last* on the command line, that is not a syntactic requirement: other arguments may follow.

---

> I am looking to have the output like the following..

It sounds like **you want formatting as provided by the [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) cmdlet**:

```
$object | Format-List >> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt
```

Note that `>` / `>>` / `Out-File` apply the *default* string formatting, i.e. the same representation that would by default *display in the console*.

By using an explicit `Format-*` cmdlet, you can control that formatting, but note two things about [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) in general:

- As you're outputting *for-display* formats, the resulting file may not be suitable for further *programmatic processing*.
- To prevent truncation of values, you may have to pass a `-Width` argument to `Out-File`, control the enumeration length of nested properties with `$FormatEnumerationLimit`, and, in the case of `Format-Table`, specify `-AutoSize`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use Write-Output at all.  Try this to just get your string to your file:

```
("Email: " + $object.EmailAddress) >> C:\psoutput\psoutput.txt
```

You don't need to specify append because '>>' already does that for you